# Under what circumstances will a backgroundworker not run the DoWork method to completion?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I've got a background worker on a form and I've written some long running DB interaction in it.

When I click a button on my form, the following runs:

```
if (!bwFind.IsBusy)
    bwFind.RunWorkerAsync(param);
```

Where bwFind is the BackgroundWorker and param is a DevExpress CriteriaOperator.

I update a progressbar in the Progress_Changed event handler.

And I do the following in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = this.dataObject;
dataGrid.Refresh();
label1.Text = this.dataObject.Count.ToString(); // problem appears here
```

Problem is, that I get a Null Ref Exception at the line noted, however I instantiate that object, at the end of the DoWork method.

I know that DoWork isn't running, cause if I do a null-check before using it, press the button on the form a second time... it runs, and all works as expected.

Maybe I'm not using the BackgroundWorker correctly, but this happens very often whenever I use the component.

Comment: This is obvious I'm sure, but you've checked the value of this.dataObject when the exception gets thrown right?

Comment: It was most certainly null, but the point is that it never should have been. It was set in DoWork (which exited due to a Cross-Threaded Operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific pattern for [implementing RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

- First, Check e`.Error` (Exceptions)
- Second, Check for Cancelation, if supported
- And finally, Accept result

And you normally assign the result to `e.Result` in DoWork to transfer it to RunWorkerCompleted, but you use a class member for that. Make sure the use of `this.dataObject` is thread-safe.

```
   void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            label1.Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            label1.Text = "Canceled";
        }
        else
        {
            // Finally, handle the case where the operation 
            // succeeded.
            label1.Text = this.dataObject.Count.ToString();
        }

        // update UI for Thread completed
    }
```

Comment: Turns out I was modifying a UI item in DoWork. Checking e.Error.Message indicated this. Thank you. I thought the whole point of using the BackgroundWorker was so that I didn't have to (Begin)Invoke?

Comment: You still have to Invoke from DoWork. (Only) the Completed and Progress events are Invoked to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more issue. You'll not get you `Complete` if the parent thread was killed/aborted.

Comment: He was getting ther null ref exception in the parent thread (== mainthread).